# PagerSlidingTabStrip and onTabUnselect

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator, android-actionbar-compat

i use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` from

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java

i am implementing an app that when user select a tab i send a request that corresponds to that tab to the server. i want to cancel those requests when the user select other tabs. i mean for example user select tab1 and i request to server called req1 now when user select tab 2 i want to cancel req1 and send req2 to server. in tab implementation of action bar there is a call back method call `onTabUnselected` and i want to implement that and integrate it to that library but i can not find where i must call that method. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PagerSlidingTabStrip` has nothing to do with the `Tabs` related to an `ActionBar` afaik, so `onTabUnselected` won't be called when de-selecting tabs in the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`. Also `Tabs` related to the `ActionBar` is deprecated in Android L.

I'd recommend you create a new variable that keeps track of the last selected tab (when using the `OnClickListener` on a tab (see line 251 in the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` class).

An example of some (not tested) code:

```
int lastClickedTabPosition;

// This method should be called from the OnClickListener of the tabs.
private void saveClickedPositionAndCancelLastRequest(int clickedPosition) {
    // Cancel your last request here by using the lastClickedTabPosition to get the last clicked position if you have more requests sent to the server.
    // Afterwards set lastClickedTabPosition with the new clicked position:
    this.lastClickedTabPosition = clickedPosition;
}
```

This variable could hold the last known clicked tab position.
Whenever you click a new tab, you simply get the last clicked tab's position and then cancel the last request send.

On a side-note: Google has created their own implementation of the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` called `SlidingTabLayout` and has opensourced it here: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html, which might be easier to use and especially get help with in the future :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: just +1 for your spending time to answer,  check it further tomorrow to accept, thank you very much !!